# Run PHP code on a specific domain only

Tags: php

I need to echo out some specific php code only on the sub-domain of a site. This is where I am so far.

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] != "http://support.demo.com")
        echo "<?php bb_head(); ?>";
?>
```

Of course if this worked I'd not be asking a question. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Host` header in HTTP request is your friend here. It can be accessed through $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'support.demo.com') {
     ...
}
```

[Documented here.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: Thanks. I was on the documentation page and just missed something obviously.

Comment: Is it possible to forge this as a header?

Answer (score 0):

Yaggo was mostly correct except that you want == instead of != if you want to echo if it matches the submdomain